# Add new fields to structure - matlab

Tags: matlab, structure

How can I add the each element in 4th field the number 7 in a better way? How can I add to a 5th field the result of user(:).billing * user(:).data?

Thanks.

Code:

```
clc;
clear;
user(1).name = 'John Doe';
user(1).billing = 1.00;
user(1).test = [79, 75, 73; 180, 178, 177.5; 220, 210, 205];
user

user(2).name = 'Jane';
user(2).billing = 7.00;
user(2).test = [7, 7, 7; 10, 178, 1; 0, 20, 5];
user

user(3).name = 'Joe';
user(3).billing = 20;
user(3).test = [57, 7, 75; 10, 178, 15; 20, 20, 5];
user

 [user(:).data] =  deal([7]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you are using for adding a new field to the structure array looks totally fine to me, although it can also be written as follows:

```
[user.data] =  deal(7);
```

The second step is trickier. I would perform it like this:

```
res = num2cell([user.billing] .* [user.data]);
[user.result] =  res{:};
```